# How to open Outlook 2016 with vs2017

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I've on my computer Office 2013 32bits. I develop an Intranet but on server and windows session of my customer : it's an Office 2016 32bits... 
On my vs2017 I install with nugget package microsoft.office.interop 15.0.4797.1003 But it's for Office 2013. 
I create mail with

```
dim outl as new outlook.application
dim Mai las outl.mailitem=outl.createItem(Micrososft.office.Interop.outlook.olitemtype.olmailItem)
Mail.To=...
...
Mail.attachment.add(MyFile)
Mail.display()
```

I try to put my code on the customer server, and like I thougth ... 80070005 Access denied...
I don't find how to open an Outlook 2016
Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**
On Property of my project, I've "Any CPU" option activate

Comment: Which line raises the exception? Is Outlook running at the time ? Id either app (including VS) running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator)?

Comment: Sorry for the late. I try with Outlook close on a account with high privilege (not admin, but close) And I need that my codes run for all people. It's a generator of quotations accessible by anyone.

Comment: So which line raises the exception?

Comment: I don't know. Cause no problem of compil on my computer. Just try on server. I try to put some traces to a file to follow the error.

Comment: You need to re-think the idea of starting Outlook on a server: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). You should be using methods in the [System.Net.Mail Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx) to create emails.

Comment: I know how make a mail with vb.net. the problem is my customer want each people send mail, they have their signature in back of email. I would avoid to do a code to build a new signature and take the official contains in ... outlook

Comment: I see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6229334e-d5ef-4016-9e7e-1c8718be8d43/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-vbnet?forum=netfxbcl) How to give rigths. I use iis apppool account. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally...
A friend says me, my method can be ok only If I open session on server. outlook.display run on server not on clientside on other computer.
Then I change my mind and build a emml file, store and push with ashx file

```
 For Each _file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Path), "*.eml")
                        IO.File.Delete(_file)
                    Next

                    Dim MailMdp As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
                    MailMdp.Subject = Vers.Devi.Libelle
                    MailMdp.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(ConnectedUser.Mail)

                        MailMdp.To.Add(AnAdress)

                    MailMdp.Body = "Bonjour,"
                    Dim att As New Net.Mail.Attachment(Path)
                    MailMdp.Attachments.Add(att)
                    MailMdp.IsBodyHtml = True

                    Dim Client As Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
                    Client.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory
                    Client.PickupDirectoryLocation = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Path)
                    Client.Send(MailMdp)

                    Dim MonEml = IO.Directory.GetFiles(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Path), "*.eml", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).First

                    Dim fso As New System.IO.FileInfo(MonEml)
                    Dim NomFichier As String = fso.Name
                    context.Response.Clear()
                    context.Response.ClearContent()
                    context.Response.ClearHeaders()
                    context.Response.ContentType = "message/rfc822"
                    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & NomFichier)
                    context.Response.TransmitFile(MonEml)
                    context.Response.End()
```

I hope that can be helpfull